# Add Meta tags and Title on hook_menu "page callback"

Tags: hooks, routes, meta-tags

How to add Meta and Title tags to the document head on **hook_menu "page callback"**?
Drupal 7

Comment: Why do you think adding meta tags have anything to do with menu hooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 7...

For the title you can use [`drupal_set_title()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7).

For the meta tags you can use [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7). Example from geerlingguy in the comments of those docs:

```
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'link', // The #tag is the html tag - <link />
  '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
    'href' => 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo&subset=latin', 
    'rel' => 'stylesheet',
    'type' => 'text/css',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'google_font_cardo');
```